# Auto generate IBM DB2 schema based on a CSV file

Tags: python, db2

I'm trying to import a large CSV file into IBm Db2 database. is there a tool (or method) to scan through the CSV file and automatically suggest the most optimal schema using python or other language? For example, if the length of the longest string of a column is 15, then it will auto create a table schema and load the data into db2?

Comment: Java has Apache Commons CSV.